# Is there any relation between VMware VMotion and VMFS?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I was studying VMware's VSphere suite, cloud computing virtualization platform.

I could not figure out whether there's any relation between VMotion and VMFS in the suite?

VMotion enables the live migration of running virtual machines from one physical server to another with zero down time.

VMFS is a clustered file system that leverages shared storage to allow multiple physical hosts to read and write to the same storage simultaneously.

Is there any relation between them?

Comment: The relationship is that you can only migrate a VM from one host to the other when both hosts can access the vm image storage. This implies a clustered solution like VMFS.

Answer (score 0):

There's no relation, other than their appropriate use-cases.

- vMotion is the ability to live-migrate virtual machines (which themselves live on VMFS datastores) between vSphere hosts (which have access to the same datastores).
- VMFS is the filesystem format used for vSphere datastores - the same as NTFS, FAT32, EXT3 and HFS+.
- The only time when the two have any kind of relationship is when you use **Storage vMotion** to live-migrate virtual machines between two VMFS datastores.